# How to use string from mainpage.xaml.cs to anotherpage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am looking for a solution since yesterday but I've not found it, if someone could help me.

So for now, i have : in *mainpage.xaml*: 2 textboxs; *TextBox Name="id"* and *TextBox Name="compte"*

i get the string from my 2 textbox in mainpage.xaml.cs and i'm doing =>

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public string url()
{
    string url_ = (myCompte() + myId());
    return url_;
}
```

`mycompte` and `myid` are public string function returning the string content of my textbox.

and I need to use `url_` in another page in C# but i don't know how.

ClassicView.xaml.cs

```
private void loadJson()
{
    string i = url();
    MessageBox.Show(i);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(i));       
}
```

It tell me that url isn't existing here.
Maybe you can help me.
Thx you

Comment: You have to use messaging services

Answer (score 1):

As for me the best solution how to communicate between more windows is through messenger. I prefer messenger [MVVM light toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). From MainPage.xaml.cs you can send message with this url and register receiving messages in ClassicView.xaml.cs to process your messages. Try to read about it e.g. on [MVVM Light Toolkit Messaging Example](http://wbsimms.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-messaging-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the URL as a static field and access it from the other Page.

Comment: Can't define it as a static because the content of my textbox aren't static, i've already try it

Comment: @Loyck, static != const

Comment: When i use a static, it say that url isn't define in wlassicview and that i can't use static if my textbox isn't static